# "Invalid IP address" error caught in android-JSON- MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to make an app that connects to a MySQL database and queries for data. I don't want to insert any data, just search for a keyword in the given entries. I found a couple of tutorials on Google, and this one worked for me.

The layout looks fine, and the app launched well (I tested the app on my actual Nexus 5). But every time I click the button, whether or not there is data in the text box, it just shows "Invalid IP address" in a toast, which I assume is the error caught. My PHP looks like this :

```
$host='*****';
$uname='*****';
$pwd='*****';
$db="*****";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$r=mysql_query("select * from ***** where id='$id'",$con);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
$flag[name]=$row[name];
}
print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

Why am I getting this error? And how do I get this to work? Any additional data needed can be provided.

**EDIT**

Android code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    String id;  
    String name;  
    InputStream is=null;  
    String result=null;  
    String line=null;  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        Button select=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            id=e_id.getText().toString();  
            select();  
        }  
    });  
    }  
    public void select()  
    {  
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));  
        try  
        {  
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            HttpPost httppost = new   HttpPost("http://kanurajb.co.nf/php/search.php");  
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);   
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
            is = entity.getContent();  
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");  
    }  
        catch(Exception e) 
    {  
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",  
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }  
        try
        {  
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader  
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);  
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  
        {  
                sb.append(line + "\n");  
            }  
                is.close();  
result = sb.toString();  
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");   
    }  
        catch(Exception e)  
        {  
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());   
    }  
    try  
        {  
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);  
            name=(json_data.getString("name"));  
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+name,  
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }    
        catch(Exception e)   
        {  
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());    
        }   
    }  
    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: please show the android code too..

Comment: hmmm, so you are coding in PHP on android platform ... interesting ...

Comment: The problem is in your application. Post your android code.

Comment: I can't post my Java code here. <a href="/kanurajb.co.nf/code.txt">Here</a> it is.

Comment: yet another NOMTException .... and no ... it is not "Invalid IP ..." ... you just  catch random exception and show unrelated toast `catch(Exception e) 
 {  
         Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());  
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",  
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
 }`

Comment: What does the log with key `Fail 1`  say?

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I realized that the error is being caught, but I have no clue what the error in the code is?

Comment: That is what i asked..You are printing the error Using Log.e..so what does the log with key `Fail 1` say?

Comment: The error says "Addressandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: See my answer below..You'll have to use AsyncTask to do network operations..

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/3168859)..It correctly tells you how to deal with the exception. It says..

> This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in
>   [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

Chenge your code as follows..I have changed your select() as follows..This is just for you to get a better understanding about `AsyncTask`.

> ```
> class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
>
>   private Exception exception;
>
>   protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
>       try {
>         Boolean failedflag=false;
>         ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
>         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));  
>         try  
>         {  
>             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
>             HttpPost httppost = new   HttpPost("http://kanurajb.co.nf/php/search.php");  
>             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
>             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);   
>             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
>             is = entity.getContent();  
>             Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");  
>         }  
>         catch(Exception e) 
>         {  
>             failedflag=true;
>             Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());           
>         }  
>         try
>         {  
>             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader  
>                 (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);  
>                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
>                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  
>                 {  
>                     sb.append(line + "\n");  
>                 }  
>                 is.close();  
>                 result = sb.toString();  
>                 Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");   
>         }  
>         catch(Exception e)  
>         {  
>             failedflag=true;
>             Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());   
>         }  
>         try  
>         {  
>             JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);  
>             name=(json_data.getString("name"));   
>         }    
>         catch(Exception e)   
>         {  
>             failedflag=true;
>             Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());    
>         }   
>         return failedflag;
>   }
>
>   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) { 
>       // TODO: do something with the flag
>       if(!flag){
>           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed",  
>         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> How to execute the task: In MainActivity.java file you can add this
>   line within your oncreate() method
>
> ```
> new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
> ```
>
> Don't forget to add this to `AndroidManifest.xml` file:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> ```

Comment: I'm kinda new to this. Could you please help a little more by adapting this concept to my code? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: the basic working of AsyncTask is that anything that has to be done, should be done in `doInBackground()` and the results obtained after performing the operations will be passed on to `onPostExecute()`.and in the  `onPostExecute()` you will be able to alter the UI based on the results returned by the `doInBackground()`. Note that you'll get an error if you try to change the UI in `doInBackground()` including showing a Toast.So all the Toasts should be shown in` onPostExecute()` only.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's kinda hard to understand to a beginner. Could you please just give me some code with comments that I can copy-paste and understand?

Comment: Network operations have to be performed inside AsyncTask, but just for you to suppress the error add `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);` after` setContentView()` and the error will be suppressed..But this is not at all recommended.

Comment: No no, can't you just give me complete code? It's hard for me to piece together methods and functions to make full code at this stage.

Comment: you just have to add `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();StrictMode.setThreadPolicy‌​(policy); after `setContentView()` in your code..try it..

Comment: Bro, I'm really not getting you. Could you please edit your answer and add the whole edited code into it?

Comment: Did you add the above said code to your actual code?

Comment: Full code please? I have no clue where to add the method, or how to create it.

Comment: Add that code which i told you after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  ` in your `onCreate()` and see if the error goes..

Comment: Dude, seriously, could you _please_ just write full code for me to copy paste?

Comment: Why dont you do what i say? Take some effort in writing the code instead of just copy pasting,..you just have to copy and paste those 2 lines that i mentioned in one of the previous comments, after the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  ` in your `onCreate()` and see if the error goes..

Comment: The type MainActivity.RetrieveFeedTask must implement the inherited abstract method 
 AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>.doInBackground(Void...)??? Help please Lal.

Comment: You just wait to do the code in my answer...hey @15KanurajBeri please undo the changes made and add the 2 lines that i said in my comments..

Comment: Hey could a give me full code with the two lines added? I am having a little trouble with it.

Comment: Replace the start of your onCreate() as follows `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();StrictMode.setThreadPolicy‌​(policy); `

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm trying that but got an error on the last line of code which is : "Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setThreadPolicy‌(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy) is undefined for the type StrictMode
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens."

Comment: OK got rid of some of it, but still have "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens" even tho there aren't any tokens to delete.

Comment: It should be `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();StrictMode.setThreadPolicy‌​(policy); `

Comment: I know that, but the "StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)" line keeps giving the error "Syntaxt error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Comment: I DON'T KNOW!!! No word is underlined! And yet the whole has an error shown! A solid red error circle, you know what I'm saying?

Comment: No! There is no ; missing anywhere!

Comment: Did you import strictmode?